# Boolean logic issue

Tags: c++, logic, boolean

I was wondering if there was a shorter way to write

```
if (test != 'e' || test != 'd')
```

I want to write it like

```
if (test != ('e' || 'd'))
```

Or something like this so i don't have to repeat "test !="

Thanks

Comment: There's a much shorter way of writing that: `if (true)`. You might want to take a look at *DeMorgan's Laws* though. In case you're wondering, if test is `d`, it won't be `e`, and if it's `e`, it won't be `d`. Therefore your condition will always be true. You probably want `&&`, not `||`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the syntax of the language. There's not much you can do about it... If you don't like the way it looks, you can make a boolean function that contains the tests and then just call that function:

```
bool isEOrD(char test)
{
    return (test != 'e' || test != 'd')
}

...

if (isEOrD(test))
```

**EDIT:** There are other ways to write this code (see the comments to this answer), but your original way is probably the cleanest approach.

Comment: Yeah that just isn't worth the trouble for such a minor issue that only has to do with simplifying. I'm only checking for 'e' or 'd' once so this would be over complication but I can see how it would be useful if I used it more than once.

Comment: This is C++, of course theres ways to do whatever crazy you want.  Boost has bits vaguely like this for adding several elements to a container.

Comment: @JDN Answering is hard on my phone, but it can be done with std::accumulate, std::bind1st, std::bind, and a function that compares inequality (theres probably a std:: for that, but I dont know it off the top of my head.

Comment: I hardly think this is a more readable solution. This is over complicating of a trivial boolean check. You shouldn't need STL help to do this.

Comment: @MooingDuck, `std::not_equal_to`

Comment: @Oleksi: I agree that STL is overkill, think the code in the OP was best.  But the STL answer is interesting, flexible, and uses fewer characters as number of inequalities grows _very_ large.  I only suggest it because this answer isn't flexible.  I like the readability though.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use the old C function [`strchr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strchr/):

```
if (!strchr("de", test))
{
    // test is not 'd' or 'e'
}
```

But I don't know whether it is any nicer to look at… personally I would probably just have the two `!=`.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I agree... but I've seen it in a few places, although moreso in C projects rather than C++ projects.

Comment: The strchr thing is not bad if you have 43 different alternatives, but for 2, it's needlessly indirect.

Answer (score 0):

C or C++ must evaluate the expressions you write in the syntax of the language.  The expression ('e' or 'd') always returns true because the 'or-ing' is done by comparing the bits of the values which will never be the same.  How is the compiler to know what you want since in C/C++ a raw character is simply an interpretation of an integer.  That's why you can legally write:

```
char aChar = 'a';
// or
char aChar = 0x41; // hex 41 = ascii 'a'
```

and have them both work.